# onTouch method if and else section both run at the same time

Tags: android

I have set this onTouchListener like so...

```
myView.setOnTouchListener
(
    new OnTouchListener()  
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)  
            {
                DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);  
                view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);=System.out.println("ACTION DOWN");
                return true;
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("ACTION UP");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

The problem is, when I click and hold it down, "action down" AND "action up" are both printed? What is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that `onTouch()` method is called every time you touch, move or leave screen. So statements in else structure is called when ACTION_DOWN not just ACTION_UP.

Here is probably what you want

```
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)  
    {
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);  
        view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);=System.out.println("ACTION DOWN");
        return true;
    }
    else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
    {
        System.out.println("ACTION UP");
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN reacts when a new touch started on the screen which is your if part here.

And your else part will execute if any type of MotionEvent executes like ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP. So screen touch will must executes atleast ACTION_MOVE  or ACTION_UP if you do something on it with ACTION_DOWN

So when you touch the screen it executes your both events.

I think you must work in multi touch so you can use both MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN and MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP which may help you a little bit more from single touch events.